# MongoDb - bounded array with empty values shows unbounded

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my novice skill to Mongodb and Mongoose, I seem to be failing miserably at this fundamental task.

I have a bounded array of 10 elements. A user can only have 10 pets, so I figured to make it bounded with set fields and empty values was the best way.

The `pets` array values are blank at the time of creation, because the user can add pets as they go along. When I look in mongo console, the `pets` array is unbounded with no fields. I also can't add values to the array.

Mongoose Schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  location: String,
  created_at: Date,
  pets: [
    { "pet0": {} },
    { "pet1": {} },
    { "pet2": {} },
    { "pet3": {} },
    { "pet4": {} },
    { "pet5": {} },
    { "pet6": {} },
    { "pet7": {} },
    { "pet8": {} },
    { "pet9": {} }
  ]
});
```

---

mongodb:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("56a3e324bdebcf801c1ca224"), "firstName" : "bob", "lastName" : "smith", "username" : "bob123", "pets" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }

---

When modifying the array:

```
UserModel.findOne({ firstName: "bob" }, 'pets', function(err, user) {
    user.pets[0] = { "name": "felix", "type": "cat" }
    user.save(function(err) { console.log(err); console.log('saved')});
});
```

output:

```
Mongoose: users.findOne({ firstName: 'bob' }) { fields: { pets: 1 } }  
null
/home/one/github/foo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:100
      doc.validate({ __noPromise: true }, function(err) {
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /home/one/github/foo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:100:11
    at DocumentArray.SchemaType.doValidate (/home/one/github/foo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:654:22)
    at DocumentArray.doValidate (/home/one/github/foo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:78:35)
    at /home/one/github/foo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1156:9
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allows you to [limit the number of elements in an array](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/). This feature has also been implemented in Mongoose as part of an `.update` query. The steps for adding an element to an array and limiting its size are as follows:

1. Push the element(s) into the array.
2. Slice the array.

This snippet of code explains how to do this using Mongoose:

```
UserModel.findOne({ firstName: "bob" }, function(err, user) {
  UserModel.update(user, {
    $push: {
      pets: {
        $each: [{ name: "felix", type: "cat" }],
        $slice: -10
      }
    }
  }, function(err, numAffected) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('updated');
  });
});
```

Comment: For some reason, this isn't appending values onto the array, even if I remove slice.